# Django Unit Testing - How to test all instances in a model?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to test all instances in a DB using Django.

I have a python script that populates the DB and I want to test every single instance if it pass the test.

I provide here a dummy *tests.py*:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app_core.models import Item
# Item model fields are: pk, first, second

class PairTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # This script populates the DB creating several Item instances
        from app_core.init import init_items

    def test_pair_elems_different(self):
        """First and second fields MUST be different inside the instance"""
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertNotEqual(item.first, item.second)
```

As you can see, I just tested a *single* instance.
Let's suppose the DB contains 1000 Item instances, what is the best way to test them all?

The only solution that pops up in my mind is using a simple FOR loop inside *test_pair_elems_different*, iterating all object and comparing each instance.

Is this approach correct in the context of unit testing best practices/principles?

Comment: Is it really necessary to test **every single one**?- shouldn't 1-5 examples be enough?- possibly even just hard-code grab a couple and hard-code test the fields. If you know ~1-5 are correct, you can probably infer the rest are

Comment: Well, there are some circumstances where the init script populating the DB is taking data from external sources, like API calls. In that case, supposing you define some constraints, like the ones in the example first!=second, you cannot trust the data source for every instance so you need to check everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way around.

You want to ensure `first != second`, right? Presumably you have a constraint on the model and it's this you're testing.

What you want is a test that tries to add a record where these 2 fields *are* equal, then test that this attempt raises the approriate constraint error.

I'm more of a pytest person myself, but I think the standard unittest framework uses `assertRaises` for this.

When you've validated that adding a record with equal values is not allowed, there is no need to go and test every instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Annotate a Column of if those two fields are equal and then filter by it.
This in fact **would** test every single item, but it wouldn't give you an error like `Item <230> failed validation`, but it'll give you a general `Items Failed`

```py
from django.db.models import Q, F,  ExpressionWrapper, BooleanField

countOfEqual = Item.objects.annotate(
  equal=ExpressionWrapper(
    Q(first=F('second')),
    output_field=BooleanField()
)).filter(equal=True).count()

self.assertEqual(countOfEqual, 0, '{0} Items have matching first & second. This should be 0'.format(countOfEqual))
```

If you did want specific items that failed you could at least chop off the `.count()` and filter through the list- this would cut down on time as you're only looping through items you already know are bad